# MYSQL Different database tables foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Is it possible reference using foreign keys in mutliple database tables?

I have one table called test1 in database db1 and that has field test1ID and another database named db2 has table test2 and that has field test1ID.I need to refer this test1ID to first database db1 table test1 field test1ID using foreign key.

Is it possibe in MYSQL?

Could anyoune please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, check this link 
http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/cross-database-foreign-keys/784/